# Riley's Journey

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Finally thought of a good Riley riddle.

> My prefix is strange when you cut off its tail,
>   My infix a prefix, just think of Orwell.
>   My suffix reversed shall affirm and agree,
>   that when whole, truly epic this journey shall be.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you be

> **ODYSSEY**?

`My prefix is strange when you cut off its tail,`

> Ody $\to$ Od $\to$ **Odd**. 
>  
>  [Confirmed by OP]: I was supposed to remove the last letter in the word **odd**, namely **d**, to make **od** (which is spelt rather strange, or odd). It was the "tail" because it was at the *end* of the word. 
>  
>  (And I noticed that since *Odysseus* is a Greek Mythology story, if we correspond the letter **d** with the fourth letter in the Greek alphabet, we get **delta** $\delta$ which looks like a tail!)

`My infix a prefix, just think of Orwell.`

> This refers to the English author [George **Orwell**](https://www.britannica.com/biography/George-Orwell) who is best known for writing the book, **1984**, of **dys**topian fiction (where the clock strikes thirteen!).

`My suffix reversed shall affirm and agree,`

> sey $\to$ **yes**.

`that when whole, truly epic this journey shall be.` / `Riley's Journey`

> That's what an **Odyssey** is about (*The Odyssey* by Homer; *Odysseus* Greek Mythology; *2001: A Space Odyssey* by Stanley Kubrick).

Comment: Your answer is correct. For the infix, think of what type of novel 1984 is. It's the prefix of that word. I'll accept when you get that.

Comment: Oohhh 1984, that explains it :D

Comment: You got it!... stupid character minimum

Comment: Also, a bit of a roundabout way to get to Od. I just meant remove the last letter of "Odd."

Comment: @ThePuzzlingPlatypus as for some feedback, the third line gave it away for me, but apart from that, it was a great riddle. In the event that you feel discouraged that this was solved so quickly, don't be! (How many riddles have I made that have been solved so quickly, I can't even remember.) It is just that this site is full of users who see all kinds of similar/different riddles everyday! If you don't feel discouraged, then I am glad, because it was a good riddle :)

Comment: Actually, I'm glad you liked that line; "sey" was very hard to clue. It apparently is a Scottish word/suffix related to cuts of beef, and any other definition was equally obscure. I was just happy I could make that rhyme. I know the Orwell rhyme was forced, but I had no other clue for "dys" in mind.

Comment: also thank you for the feedback, and i'm glad you liked it.

Comment: @ThePuzzlingPlatypus you are very welcome :)